# Top 3 values per record

Tags: ms-access

I have an access data file for a tournament. I need to query the top 2 values out of up to 4 values entered per record. That value will then be used to sort the totals of all enties. I know how to find the max value but not the top 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Open your query in *Design View*.

In the Property Sheet of your Query, you have the option *Top Values*.

Set that option to `2` instead of `All`.